# NSDate strange hour

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a strange hour computation. Take this log:

```
NSLog(@"Load Data in event %@ %d",currentDate,[currentDate hour]);
```

In the logs:

```
Load Data in event 2013-09-18 06:30:00 +0000 2147483647
```

where currentDate is an NSDate an the category of NSDate is:

```
- (int)hour
{
     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit |    NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
     [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
     NSInteger hour = [components hour];
     return hour;
}
```

Comment: I think I messed up some pointer...although the Sulthan'comment is right: it is better to set the timeZone on the calendar

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Today's date: %@",today);



unsigned hourAndMinuteFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSDateComponents* travelDateTimeComponents = [calendar components:hourAndMinuteFlags fromDate:today];


NSString* hours = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", [travelDateTimeComponents hour]];

NSString* minutes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", [travelDateTimeComponents minute]];



NSLog(@"Hours: %@",hours);

NSLog(@"Minutes: %@",minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove

`[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];`

Note that `NSDateComponents` don't perform any time-zone calculations so setting a time zone on them before querying a value has no meaning.

Comment: I assure you that if I remove the date are misaligned. I do not why.

Comment: @giuseppe Set the time zone on the calendar before you request the components.

Answer (score -1):

Try use below code:

```
NSString *strCurrentDate;
NSString *strNewDate;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
strCurrentDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDate *newDate= [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
strNewDate = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
NSLog(@"New Date and Time: %@",strNewDate)
```

Comment: I need the hour as int

Comment: you can get hour from newDate